# Считывание данных из файла через FileInputStream

Tags: android, android-studio, файлы

Имеется метод:

```
private void readFromFile(String path){
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        try {
            fin = openFileInput("fitnessApp/app/src/Articles/"+path+".txt");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[fin.available()];
            fin.read(bytes);
            String text = new String(bytes);
            textView.setText(text);
            fin.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Задача - считать данные из файла и поместить текст в textView. Для хранения файла создал специальный каталог, путь к которому в Android Studio

> fitnessApp/app/src/Articles

Однако при выполнении выдает ошибку:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{asus.example.com.fitnessapp/asus.example.com.fitnessapp.ArticleActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File
>   fitnessApp/app/src/Articles/ten_ways.txt.txt contains a path separator
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
>                         at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>                         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>                         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File fitnessApp/app/src/Articles/ten_ways.txt.txt contains a path separator
>                         at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:2526)
>                         at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:559)
>                         at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:202)
>                         at asus.example.com.fitnessapp.ArticleActivity.readFromFile(ArticleActivity.java:49)
>                         at asus.example.com.fitnessapp.ArticleActivity.onCreate(ArticleActivity.java:31)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)

В чем проблема? При вызове метода полный путь не передаю, а передаю только название файла, например ten_ways

Comment: У Вас две ошибки: во-первых приложение не может читать файлы из папки проекта - оно не имеет физического доступа к файлам компьютера; во-вторых метод `openFileInput(...)` открывает файл из строго определённой папки и поэтому принимает только имя файла без путей.

Comment: @woesss,понял,спасибо, примерно так и предполагал. Но тогда такой вопрос. Где мне хранить эти файлы? Каждый раз же я не буду их создавать где-то на устройстве? Можно их вообще каким-то образом привязать к самому приложению,чтобы потом, когда приложение устанавливается, эти файлы автоматически создавались в каком-нибудь каталоге приложения

Comment: Если эти файлы только для чтения (писать в них не планируется), то можно разместить их в `assets`. Пример можно посмотреть здесь: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/assets.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя два раза расширение файла `*.txt` повторяется. В переменной `path` имя содержится уже с расширением видимо. Попробуй вот так:

```
openFileInput("fitnessApp/app/src/Articles/"+path)
```